# Usage of Device Administrator

Tags: android, device-admin

How to restrict an Application uninstalling from a device. Is it possible to use device administrator for this?
Is it possible to disable camera from device by using device admin? I also see other questions related to this but didn't get anything. Help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict your application from uninstalling from a device you are able to use Device Administrator class. Here is the below link which contains easy explanation. Take a look over it.

[What is a use of device administrator in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975683/what-is-a-use-of-device-administrator-in-android/42671292#42671292)

It consists of Device Administrator class, its XML file, manifest code as well as its usage and functionalities.

Yes, it is possible to disable camera from device by using Device Administrator class as Device Administrator specifies that the camera should be disabled by using it. Note that this doesn't have to be a permanent disabling. The camera can be enabled/disabled dynamically based on context, time, and so on. Introduced in Android 4.0.
Hope the provided link and above answer will be helpful to you.